# How to change file name of a file uploaded inside wiki while keeping change history?

Tags: wiki, wikimedia

inside wiki I have this: `[[file:MF - AAA - QC Sheet.pdf]]`, which links to the actual PDF file.

**What I need**.

I need to change the file name (remove `AAA -`), while keeping change history of the file, but so far have had no luck.

**What I have tried**

- directly editing the link (which does not change file name but breaks the link)
- uploading a new file (with a new file name) and changing the link (for some reason wiki says I have broken links and does not let me click to the file)- plus, now I have two files, and wiki gives me a duplicate file warning)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should try is to move the file. Go to http://yourdomain/wiki/Special:MovePage/File:MF - AAA - QC Sheet.pdf and enter the new name.

Comment: looks like just the thing. Thanks, going to try it and see.